# Check if path matches dynamic route string

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have this pathnames:

```
const pathnames = ['/test', '/test/40', '/hello/2/testing/4'];
```

and then I have this array:

```
const routes = [
  { name: 'Test', path: '/test' },
  { name: 'Test Edit', path: '/test/:id' },
  { name: 'Hello', path: '/hello/:id/testing/:id2' },
];
```

I need a function that I pass a string (which is the current path) and returns, after searching the array, the correct object.

I thought of simply using a `.find()` but I can't match directly since some routes might be dynamic. Also, I can't use a `.includes()` either, for the same reason.

I'm using React Router DOM so maybe there's an integrated way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build a regular expression and replace parts with `:`.

```js
const
    pathnames = ['/test', '/test/40', '/hello/2/testing/4'],
    routes = [{ name: 'Test', path: '/test' }, { name: 'Test Edit', path: '/test/:id' }, { name: 'Hello', path: '/hello/:id/testing/:id2' }],
    escapeDots = s => Array.from(s, c => c === '.' ? '\\.' : c).join(''),
    result = pathnames.map(path => routes.find(o => new RegExp(`^${o.path
        .split('/')
        .map(s => s.startsWith(':') ? '[^\/]+': escapeDots(s))
        .join('\/')
    }$`).test(path)));

console.log(result);
```